# Limit as $x\to 0$ of $x\sin(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find limit as $x \to 0$ of $x\sin(1/x)$?

For $x^2\sin(1/x)$, I know it's $0$ since by the Squeeze theorem, $-x^2 \le x^2\sin(1/x) \le x^2$, but for $x\sin(1/x)$, I run into some problems when applying Squeeze theorem.

Comment: What difficulties? Which squeeze inequality do you get?

Comment: Why there's a problem? just replace $x^2$ by $x$

Comment: Or, better, by $|x|$.

Comment: It's not true that $-x \le x\sin(1/x) \le x$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Not true when $x < 0$.  Try $|x|$ rather than $x$.

Comment: Maybe you could use L'Hopitals Rule?

Comment: You have $-|x|\le x\sin(1/x)\le |x|$. Now give it the Squeeze.

Comment: @DavidMitra Since $0 \le |x\sin(1/x)| \le |x|$, by squeeze theorem $\lim_{x \to 0} |x\sin(1/x)| = 0$, which implies $\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin(1/x) = 0$.

Valid?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But you're appealing to an additional theorem, there (if $|a_n|\rightarrow0$, then $a_n\rightarrow0$). This is OK of course, if you have that in your bag of tricks. Otherwise, just use the inequality in my last comment.

Comment: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$  Also, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x| < \delta$ implies $||f(x)|| = |f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)| = 0$.   But both statements are saying the same thing?  Does that justify it?

Comment: Yes, it does.${}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the Squeeze Theorem, we do know that $0\leq|x \sin(1/x)|\leq|x|,\;$ so by the squeeze theorem $$\;\lim_{x\to 0} |x \sin(1/x)|=0,\;\implies \; \lim_{x\to 0} x \sin(1/x)=0.$$

Comment: This is already better than my day! :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

- For $x>0$ use the squeeze theorem and the inequality
  $$-x\leq x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq x$$
- Do the same thing for $x<0$ or better use the fact that the function $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is even.

Comment: How about just: $-|x|\leq x\sin\frac1x\leq |x|$ instead of breaking into cases?

Comment: Well, for the elementary result perhaps the more elementary and detailed methods are best for beginners.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how is the above inequality true?

Comment: @Idonotknow $ -1\leq \sin\theta \leq 1$

Comment: I know this piece of information ..... then what?@ThomasAndrews